# What is the difference between an OCR code repo on GitHub and their website where they bill you for it?

Tags: python, github, deep-learning, ocr

I've been trying to look for models that I can use/train as a license plate detector and recognizer. Thing is every time I come across a GitHub repo, they offer off the shelf instructions on how to install dependencies, ready up the model, train and inference.

What confuses me though, is sometimes they link to their website in order to get some API key to go with the code in order to continue training the model and i'm not sure whether the billing aspect of their website often refers to something that hinders me using their GitHub code or refers to something completely irrelevant like billing people to use the GUI (i.e. their website) to train a model instead of flat out doing it yourself from a CLI using their code.

Can someone shed some light on how this generally works?

TLDR: I'm looking, on GitHub, to use/train a model for an ALPR task but most link to their website as part of the instructions on how to continue with their code. How do I know when their websites, that include billings, actually hinder me from using their code on GitHub? (i.e. I don't want to pay for anything. I'd rather train and inference it myself)

- Example repo: https://github.com/NanoNets/nanonets-ocr-sample-python
- Website they link: http://app.nanonets.com/#/keys

Comment: If you host it yourself, you pay for the hosting and bandwidth.

Comment: I'm still not getting it. Could you put it in laymen terms? (i.e. hosting what?)

Comment: What they are charging you for is not using their code; they are charging you for using their servers, which cost money to run. If you run the code locally, or on your own server, they won't charge you for that.

Comment: Oh so just to get the complete picture, payments (under these contexts) are usually referring to them taking care of the hosting + some added benefits (like user friendly UIs) and not the license to commercially use the code right? (P.S I'm also thinking of commercially using the codes capabilities)

Comment: I haven't studied the specific license in your case but you seem to be asking about the general case anyway.  Contact them and/or a lawyer for an authoritative verdict anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are github repos of companies, they basically show a demo with their API's and there developers who upload it as a project or whatever. The Company you gave as an example shows a demo of their API's and asks you to buy a key and without that key you won't be able to access their API's I.e they are like a key to your house.
What you have to do is make an API and host it. Here you want to do a license plate detector and recognize the character right? So what suggestion I have for you is:

1. Make a haar-cascade classifier for detecting the number plate
2. Train a mnist model in scikit or whatever library you prefer.
3. Make a flask application of the same or any other web framework app
4. Host it Heroku
5. Heroku is a like a computer in cloud you can deploy several application and deploy it.
   6.but everything is not free there for example if you want to name your website car-detector, you won't be able to do in free tier instead your url will look like car-detector.herokuapp.com and if you want a custom domain you have to pay for it and also, if you want to increase the performance of the app you have to pay for it

Here is an flask opencv python app for you to start with
https://github.com/dev-Roshan-lab/flask-opencv-app

Regards,
Roshan